# How to determine the matrix?

Tags: matrices

Definition of $\mathbf{S}$
    $$S(a, b, c) \equiv (a + b + c)^2 - 2(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) - 4abc$$
So if I expand this I get
    $$S(a, b, c) = 2ab + 2ac + 2bc - a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - 4abc$$
               $$ = 4(1 - a)(1 - b)(1 - c) - (a + b + c - 2)^2$$
               $$ = -det\begin{pmatrix}0&a&b&1\\a&0&c&1\\b&c&0&1\\1&1&1&2\end{pmatrix}$$
Using row echelon form I checked that the negative of the determinant of the matrix is equal to the first equation that resulted from my expanding the original $\mathbf{S}$. I have yet to make a determination on the second equation.
But I realized that I do not know where this matrix came from. By this I mean, I do not know how I would set up the matrix.
For instance I can setup the matrix for say three points, $\mathbf{a_1}, \mathbf{a}_2, \mathbf{a}_3$ where $\mathbf{a}_1 \equiv [x_1 y_1 z_1]$ etc such that each row of the 3x3 matrix is comprised of the components of $\mathbf{a_1}, \mathbf{a}_2, \mathbf{a}_3$ such that the 3x3 matrix looks like:
    $$\begin{pmatrix}x_1&y_1&z_1\\x_2&y_2&z_2\\x_3&y_3&z_3\end{pmatrix}$$
But I do not have the same clarity as to how to setup the 4x4 matrix.
Any suggestions or links that could give me guidance as to how to setup this 4x4 matrix given that all I would have is the equations I listed above.

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde. Lets assume I did not have the 4x4 matrix but I only had **S** and its expansion. Then I need to setup a 4x4 matrix and this is where I find I do not know how to setup this matrix and I was hoping for some help in doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial answer for finding such a $4\times 4$-matrix is as follows:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} S(a,b,c) & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Its determinant is $S(a,b,c)$. If you want a more specific matrix, this is also possible. But you have to say what you want.

Comment: Thanks ... Okay I would like to know how to setup the matrix I show in my OP that is equivalent to the expansion of **S**. My apologies if this is not clear.

Comment: Can you say which properties exactly you would like to have the matrix $A$? So far I can only see that you want $n=4$ and $\det(A)=S(a,b,c)$. Or do you want to know why $S(a,b,c)=4(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)-(a+b+c-2)^2$?

Comment: As I look at the 4x4 matrix I am trying to understand how I would write down this matrix if all I was given was the equation S and more specifically its expansion. I see that the 4x4 matrix consists of a symmetric 3x3 matrix padded in the 4th column and row by 1's and ending up with a two. My question is directed at trying to understand what is it in S and its expansion that informs me how to write down this matrix.

Comment: I do see in the first expansion that the first term is **ab** and it appears in **A** in row 1 col 2 and col 3, also the second term **bc** which appears in **A** in row 2 col 1 and col 3 etc. But I do not understand the zero in **A** in row 1 col 1 nor the 1's padding row 4 col 4 and finally the entry 2. I hope this is explicit enough ... thanks.

Comment: Just a quick correction to my last comment. I understand the zero in **A** in row 1 col 1 since it is part of the 3x3 symmetrical matrix. But the padded 1's  in row 4 col 4 and the final entry of 2 still evade me ... thanks.

Comment: I still don't see why you can't take the matrix of my answer then.

Comment: I will accept it since I do not have sufficient knowledge in mathematics to understand it, and I suppose for someone who does have this knowledge, your answer is all they need. It does not however bring me any closer to the resolution I was asking for in my original posting, but as I have already suggested this most likely is due to the fact that I do not have the knowledge necessary to see the solution in your answer ... thanks for your patience and your answer.

Comment: I am sorry that you still have no satisfying answer; I would like to help you, but I don't understand why you only want the $4\times 4$-matrix you gave, if other (much easier) matrices have the same determinant $S(a,b,c)$. If you want, try to formulate a new question, as short and as concise as possible, so that everyone can understand what you need.

Comment: I think I have the final piece of the puzzle, that is for me. The 0001 shown in the last row and column shown in the trivial answer has to do with rotation but not translation ... so the 1112 in the last row and column of my OP might mean that translation is included and or it could be the format required for a projective matrix. I will research some more ... thanks.